# Can we modify domain name in existing Topology?

Tags: topology-manager

I am facing one issue while setting up the New Domain in the existing Topology. It doesn't allow me to update the `PrimaryMappedUrl` in the existing Topology.

One approach is to:

- Unpublish all items from that Publication
- Remove the Mapping & add a new Mapping

But I can't unpublish the items from PROD env.

Is there any alternate way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the domain you can use this command:

```
Set-TtmWebsite -Id Your_Website_ID -Baseurls @("https://new-domain-host")
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the running the `Set-TTmWebsite` command noted by Velu, you'll also need to resync the configuration to the Content Delivery environment using PowerShell:

```
Sync-TtmCdEnvironment -Id [Content_Delivery_Environment_ID]
```

Comment: Are you sure that is always necessary? I was under the impression that synchronization would happen automatically in most cases.

Comment: I've always explicitly run it after making any changes. The SDL online documentation is unclear, but it only seems to be mentioned after using `Import-TtmCdStructure` there, so I suspect that you may be right! I'll test it out next time I'm playing with Topology Manager and report back.

Comment: Changes should indeed be propagated to the Discovery Service automatically and it should normally not be needed to use the `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Rick. Presumably this sync only needs to needs to be done after using `Import-TtmCdStructure` then, as that's the only place it's mentioned in the online docs.